# How can i Integrate FullCalendar with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am using Codeigniter. I am trying to integrate FullCalendar with my project. It is working. But, i am not able to save the events in database(mysql) using codeigniter. Is it possible to save selected events to database with date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, It's possible. you can put your AJAX call whenever a event create/updated/deleted with fullcalendar events and you can save the data into database. Checkout the below library which shows basic **CRUD operations of FullCalendar with codeigniter**.

https://github.com/eboominathan/Basic-Crud-in-Full-Calendar-Using-Codeigniter-3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to setup some kind of mysql table which can store the events. From [FullCalendar with PHP & CodeIgniter](https://www.patchesoft.com/fullcalendar-with-php-and-codeigniter):

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_events` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`start` datetime NOT NULL,
`end` datetime NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Then you can insert events into it using the start and end datetimes provided by the library.

When you need to grab them, use the start and end dates that FC provides.